# Setting Text fields Limit

Tags: textfield

I have a textfield.
I want to make this field accept ONLY 10 digits, and throw an error if the digits entered are more than 10 or less than 10

```
<td><input name="Number" type="text" id="Number" value="" required/></td>

    document.getElementById('Number').onchange = function()
    {
          if(this.value > 11){
               this.value = "Please Check the Ticket Number Again";
          }
          if(this.value < 10){
               this.value = "Please Check the Ticket Number Again";
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<td><input name="Number" type="text" id="Number" value="" required/></td>

    document.getElementById('Number').onchange = function()
    {
          if(this.value.length != 10){
               this.value = "Please Check the Ticket Number Again";
          }

    }
```

Comment: Worked..Thanks a lot.That was quick.. :)